# Deleting from Database in Java wamp server

Tags: java, mysql, database, wamp

```
public void deleteBook(int temp)
{
    try
    {
        query = "DELETE FROM ccItems WHERE ISBN = '"+temp+"'";

        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Deleted !");
    }      

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not find ISBN or Already deleted.");
    }
}
```

I have a `deleteBook()` method where it would delete items in my database. It works properly meaning deleting the specified item with the corresponding ISBN entered. Problem is, if the user inputs an ISBN which *is not in my database* the `try` statement still executes. I think the `catch` statement must execute because the entered ISBN is not found in database.

Comment: I could comment so would you mind helping me here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535629/record-not-getting-deleted-from-mysql-databases-table-while-its-deleted-from-j

Answer (score 0):

The try will still run. It just deletes 0 rows.

You need to use the return value of [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29). Since executeUpdate() returns an int;  the number of entities updated or deleted you can use it to solve your problem. You can just throw an exception to get your error message.

```
public void deleteBook(int temp)
{
    try
    {
        query = "DELETE FROM ccItems WHERE ISBN = '"+temp+"'";
        if (stmt.executeUpdate(query)!=0) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Deleted !");
        } else {
          throw new Exception();
        }
    }      
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not find ISBN or Already deleted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark as answered, thats how you thank people on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As in a select query, 'No records found' is not an exception.`stmt.executeUpdate(query);` will return the number of records deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From database point of view **that is not an error at all**, it just didn't find any matching records given your where condition.
That's why you don't have exception thrown on client.

Answer (score 0):

if i input something to make temp equals ' or ''=',all your ccItems will be deleted,that is a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

It won't give any error because if the ISBN does not exist, it just effects zero rows without any error.

If you want to know exactly if any row is deleted, write the code like this.

```
public void deleteBook(int temp){
   try{
        query = "DELETE FROM ccItems WHERE ISBN = '"+temp+"'";
        int numberOfRowsEffected = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if (numberOfRowsEffected == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not found !");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Deleted !");
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not find ISBN or Already deleted.");
    }
}
```