# Record not getting deleted from MySQL database's table while it's deleted from Java GUI?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

### Edited Question

When I click the delete button, The row in the table gets deleted in GUI but not from database in mysql server.

Here's the code:

//  DatabaseStore. This part runs fine.

```
public class DatabaseStore {

     private final String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    private final String database = "music_magic";
    private final String user_name = "root";
    private final String pass_word = "";

    private final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    public Connection doConnection() {
        Connection c;
        try {
            //load the driver
            Class.forName(driver);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(server + database, user_name, pass_word);
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return c;
    }
```

//

```java
// Imports
import Database_music.DatabaseStore; //main database page where i connect to database
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import magic_music.Items; //ignore this
//...

// Subject method
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  if(jTable1.getSelectedRow() >=0){
    try{
      DatabaseStore dtbs = new DatabaseStore();
      Connection cn = dtbs.doConnection();
      Statement stat = cn.createStatement();
      String sql = "DELETE FROM products_info WHERE Product_id ='"+jTable1.getSelectedRow() +"'";
      stat.executeUpdate(sql);
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
      model.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException)
    {
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sql err");
    }
  } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select an item to delete");
  }
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if the incomplete SQL statement has something to do with it ...

Comment: "/*What do i put here? */" is this your actual code?  If so, that's your problem -- you're not submitted any value for product_id.

Comment: I've modified the whole thing. Please tell me where i did wrong.

Comment: Try `cn.commit();` and `cn.close();`

Comment: I'm beginner so it's kinda hard to understand haha. I got error. it says "Can't call commit when autocommit=true"

Comment: You won't get any help with this snippet. You have to provide the minimal amount of code lines that can help others reproduce or track your issue.
There is a lot of dark corners such as `DatabaseStore`, `model`...

Comment: There's no problem with database store. It connects perfectly. But still, i've added it.